# Oracle - Calling .bat file (which calls to an R file) from inside a Java stored procedure

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, java-stored-procedures

I'm currently using Oracle 12c Standard Edition.

I have created a Java class and compiled it using the JDK 6 (because Oracle 12c has default support for JDK 6). The class goes as following:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Run_Batch
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException
    {       
       Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start execute_r.bat", null, new File("C:/Users/Admin/workspace/"));

    }

}
```

My goal is to create a Java stored procedure, which I can call through Oracle using PL/SQL. The Java stored procedure would call the main() method from the Run_Batch class, spawn a new OS process (presumably) and run the execute_r.bat batch file found in the C:/Users/Admin/workspace directory. After that, the .bat file would run a .R file, which would create a new table inside the Oracle database, using the ROracle library.

The code for the .bat file goes as follows:

```
path
Rscript run_signal.R
pause
exit
```

Both the .bat and the .R files are found inside of the C:/Users/Admin/workspace directory.

The code for the .R file is:

```
library(ROracle)
drv <- dbDriver("Oracle")
host <- "win-2h3vud23lai"
port <- 1521
sid <- "oracle"
connect.string <- paste(
"(DESCRIPTION=",
"(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=", host, ")(PORT=", port, "))",
"(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=", sid, ")))", sep = "")
con <- dbConnect(drv, username = "C##USER",
             password = "password",dbname=connect.string)

createTable <- "CREATE TABLE IRIS_TABLE (time_stamp VARCHAR2(55), 
category VARCHAR2(15), type VARCHAR2(55), 
servername VARCHAR2(15), code VARCHAR2(15), msg VARCHAR2(255))"
```

I've followed the small Oracle tutorial on Java stored procedure and I have already compiled my Run_Batch.java file using javac and loaded the Java file into the database using:

```
loadjava -user C##USER/password Run_Batch.class
```

After that, I have entered SQLPLUS.exe and I have created both a package and a package body:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE run_r_package AS
PROCEDURE run_test_batch ( ARGUMENTS VARCHAR2 )
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY run_r_package AS
PROCEDURE run_test_batch( ARGUMENTS VARCHAR2) 
AS LANGUAGE JAVA
NAME 'Run_Batch.main(java.lang.String[])';
END;
```

I have created the package with the package body successfully.
However, I'm not able to run the Java stored procedure nor to call the run_r_batch() procedure. Whenever I try to do so I get errors to undefined classes, undefined errors or weird exception names.

I haven't been able to make the Oracle documentation (found here: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDEV/chseven.htm#JJDEV13283) to work.

Using the sqlplus, if I do:

```
CALL run_test_batch('123');
```

I get the following error:

**ORA-06576: not a valid function or procedure name**

if, instead of using CALL, I use EXECUTE, as follows:

```
EXECUTE run_test_batch('123');
```

I get the following error:

**ORA-06550: line 1, column 7
PLS-00201: the identifier 'run_test_batch' must be declared 
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7
PL/SQL: statement ignored.**

If I use SQL Developer instead of SQLPLUS, after I connect to my user C##USER with my password, I try to run the procedure using the following code:

```
BEGIN
    run_r_package.run_test_batch('');
END;
```

the first time I got the message:

Execution terminated due to unresolved exception:

**ORA-29532: java call terminated by uncaught java exception: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
ORA-06512: in "C##USER.RUN_R_PACKAGE", line 2**

But now, when I tried to run the code again I get a different message:

**ORA-29532: java call terminated by uncaught java exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
ORA-06512: in "C##USER.RUN_R_PACKAGE", line 2**

$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
EDIT
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$

I tried to refine my class and run a simple Windows command as suggested in the comments.

The new Java file goes as follows:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Run_Batch
{
    public static void proc() throws InterruptedException, IOException
    {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c cmd.exe", null, null);

    }

}
```

My package creation code has been modified as following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE run_r_package AS
PROCEDURE run_test_batch
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY run_r_package AS
PROCEDURE run_test_batch
AS LANGUAGE JAVA
NAME 'Run_Batch.proc()';
END;
```

If I use botch CALL or EXECUTE in sqlplus.exe I get the same error saying run_test_batch must be declared.

If I try to call the procedure via SQL Developer like this:

```
BEGIN
    run_r_package.run_test_batch;
END;
```

I get the errors:

**ORA-29531: no method proc in class Run_Batch
ORA-06512: en "C##USER.RUN_R_PACKAGE", line 2
ORA-06512: en line 2**

Comment: You know this will only work on Windows, and all the underlying applications (R, etc.) need to be accessible from the Windows service that is running Oracle.  Seems like a very convoluted exercise. " errors to undefined classes, undefined errors or weird exception names", such as??

Comment: Yes. But everything is running inside the same machine, which is acting as both client and server. It's just an exercise I was asked to do at work, because they don't want to pay for the Oracle R connection libraries/packages. So this is the "simplest" workaround I found.

Comment: Please edit your question, and show the errors.  People here are not mind readers.

Comment: You are right, thank you. I have just added the 4 different error messages I get whenever I try to run the code.

Comment: I'd also suggest doing this step by step.  Write a Java stored proc that just makes a simple operating system call rather than using a batch file and an R program (at least initially).  That leaves many fewer things to debug.  Off the top of my head, your Java code takes a string array but the PL/SQL wrapper takes a single string.  The Java code doesn't actually seem to use the parameter so perhaps it should be redefined to take no parameters.  Alternately, define it (and the PL/SQL) wrapper to take a scalar `String`.

Comment: @JustinCave. Just did as suggested. Now I get a different (and weird) error.

Comment: I'd skip the Java and look at a dbms_scheduler external job to call the script directly. http://www.orafaq.com/node/2850 and http://msutic.blogspot.com.au/2013/10/oracle-scheduler-external-jobs-and.html

Comment: Does it work on Windows Server too? I did a quick search and seems to work only on Linux

Comment: It doesn't work, sadly. But good, I'll consider it when running on Linux if asked.